# A column insert or update conflicts with a rule imposed by a previous CREATE RULE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000, odbc

I'm working on a online game. I got some problems with inserting new data to table. I'm getting

> 2010-4-8 2:14, 37000, 513,
>   [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server
>   Driver][SQL Server]A column insert or
>   update conflicts with a rule imposed
>   by a previous CREATE RULE statement.
>   The statement was terminated. The
>   conflict occurred in database
>   'KN_online', table 'ACCOUNT_CHAR',
>   column 'strAccountID'., 261
>   NationSelect

in logs. What does this means? How can i fix this?

I've tried to delete RULE for my DB but I'm unable to delete RULE. I'm getting  `the rule 'dbo.unallowedchars' cannot be dropped because it is bounded to one or more clumn.`

I set all permissions right but its still not working.. thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd want to:

a) Understand why someone bound the rule in the first place. If you don't know why the rule is there, I'd suggest a bit of investigation before proceeding. Are you going to break some other area of the application by putting in inappropriate characters?

b) Use the stored procedure [sp_unbindrule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190354.aspx) (2008 link, but applies to 2000 equally well), to unbind the rule from the column.